# How to restart/reload the jquery UI resizable function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, aspect-ratio, jquery-ui-resizable

The question seems strange I guess but let me explain the problem:

On my website I have 3 resizable objects. All resizable divs have the same class. At the beginning I initialize the resizable function with:

```
$('.class_of_the_3_divs').resizable({
     aspectRatio: aspect_ratio,
     handles: 'se',
     containment: '#wrapper',
     ...
});
```

Because not all resizable divs are visible at the same time and the aspect ratio changes I would like to reload the function so that the current aspect ratio will be passed. Is that possible? I don't wanna write the resizable function with all the options again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try:

```
var func = function() {
   $('.class_of_the_3_divs').resizable({
      ...
   });
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
   func();
   ...
});
```

Your 'resizable' function is called once after loading the document, and, you can call it later, too.

Comment: Yeah thx. Your code works of course but there is also a built in function that leads to a better performance. I just saved my settings in a variable var settings={...} and called $('.my_selector').resizable(settings); after document ready and when my aspect ratio variable changes I called $(".presentation").resizable("destroy"); and the function from above again. But my problem was that the se handler icon was at the wrong position and that was caused by the wrong order of my variables. I set the height variable based on the aspect ratio variable before the new aspect ratio was there. Silly me

Comment: To increase the performance, you can limit the search area by selecting a common parent of the divs: `$('common_parent').children('.class_of_the_3_divs').resizable(..)`